# Make pep8 enforce E226

Tags: python, pep8

The `pep8` command versions 1.4.x ignore E226 (whitespace around arithmetic operator) by default since PEP 8 does not enforce them.

Is there a way to turn ON E226 for the `pep8` command in the newer versions?  i.e. make it require whitespace around arithmetic operators.

Answer (score 0):

this is from the pep source code

```
if len(code) < 4 and any(s.startswith(code)
                         for s in self.options.select):
    return False
return (code.startswith(self.options.ignore) and
        not code.startswith(self.options.select))
```

so I would try

select=Exxx